# How to get the last inserted row via Odata service

Tags: odata, sapui5

Update:
Using ODATA, How to get the last inserted row in `/MySet` where MySet.Name = "abc".
I do not want to continuously poll the odata service via `model.read()`. I know `attachChange() or attachDataReceived()`methods can be use to get notified automaically. But apart from notification, how to get the 'inserted row'. Also My doubt is how to satisfy the following three conditions here : `$top=1, $orderby= Date desc and $filter=NAME eq 'ABC'`

The only solution I can think of is to get notified by data inserted via attachDataReceived() and then make a model.read() call with the required filters and additional parameters. Although this would result in these additional 'read' calls.

---

Original Post Below:
Question: How to pass filters in element binding?
Post: I am using odata service for populating my views.
I want to pass certain filters like `$filter=NAME eq 'Scott'` 
Since I want these parameters to be included only when with odata request for a specific ui-element, I want to include them in `bindElement()`

specifically something like this

```
var myFilter = new Array();
myFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("NAME", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'Scott'));
var myStandardTile = this.byId("__tile3");
myStandardTile .bindElement("/MySet",{filters:myFilter});
```

But unfortunately this does not works. When I see the 'network' tab in developer console, Filters are  not being added with my request.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Neither filter nor sorter nor formatter are supported by element bindings. They are only supported by list and tree bindings.

Comment: Thanks. Then how can I implement $filter options only for a specific ui element. Scenario: Get the latest row in MySet where 'name = abc' and update the label/button-text.